# add exception attribute to a class?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm using vb.net and .net 2 in a .net web site

Is it possible to add a ( I think its called an exception attribute ) to a code behind class, so that if any exception happens in the class but only to that class then I can exit any function in that class and do something with the exception

Is this possible or do you have another idea?

What I am trying to do is if any exception occurs then stop immediately and return the exception.

Thanks for your advice.

```
<add exception attribute>
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim result As String = "all fine"

        doOne()


        If Exception Then

            result = Exception.Message

        End If

        Return result

    End Sub



    Private Sub doOne()

        doTwo()
        Throw New ApplicationException("Exception Occured")
    End Sub

    Private Sub doTwo()

        Throw New ApplicationException("Exception Occured")
    End Sub

    Private Sub doThree()
        doOne()
        Throw New ApplicationException("Exception Occured")
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: `What I am trying to do is if any exception occurs then stop immediately and return the exception.` - that already happens. If you do not handle an exception, the thread will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at and using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/):

> ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable. It can be dynamically added to a running ASP.NET web application, or even all ASP.NET web applications on a machine, without any need for re-compilation or re-deployment.